# How do I NDSolve a system like this?

Tags: differential-equations

I have a complicated system of differential equations in which a function depends on another function, like this:

```
D[p[x[t]],t]==x[t]^2
D[x[t],t] == p[x[t]] x[t]^2
```

If I try to insert these equations in `NDSolve` it complaints that there are fewer variables than equations: how do I correctly solve a system like this?

**EDIT** I should have been more clear: this is just a MWE , I am interested in a general method of solution

Comment: And I suppose what you mean is that you would like to have as a solution `p[x] ->...` and `x[t] ->...` (as opposed to `p[t] ->...`)?  One could construct `p[x]` from `q[t]=p[x[t]]` and `x[t]`, at least if `x[t]` is invertible (e.g. monotonic).

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes I want p as a function of x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eli = Eliminate[{D[p[x[t]], t] == x[t]^2, 
                 D[x[t], t] == p[x[t]] x[t]^2}, x'[t]]
```

**Edit**

```
{psol1, psol2} = p /. DSolve[eli /. x[t] -> x, p, x]

(*   {Function[{x}, -Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x + C[1]]], 
      Function[{x}, Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x + C[1]]]}   *)

eli2 = Eliminate[{D[p[x[t]], t] == x[t]^2, 
         D[x[t], t] == p[x[t]] x[t]^2}, p'[x[t]]]

DSolve[eli2 /. p -> psol1 /. C[1] -> d1, x, t]

(*   {{x -> Function[{t}, 
      InverseFunction[
  ArcTanh[Sqrt[d1 + #1]/Sqrt[d1]]/d1^(3/2) - Sqrt[d1 + #1]/(
    d1 #1) &][-Sqrt[2] t + C[1]]]}}   *)

DSolve[eli2 /. p -> psol2 /. C[1] -> d1, x, t]

(*   {{x -> Function[{t}, 
     InverseFunction[
  ArcTanh[Sqrt[d1 + #1]/Sqrt[d1]]/d1^(3/2) - Sqrt[d1 + #1]/(
    d1 #1) &][Sqrt[2] t + C[1]]]}}   *)
```

Do the same with NDSolve

```
pnsol = p /. 
   First@NDSolve[p[1] == 1 && eli /. x[t] -> x, p, {x, 1, 6}]

Plot[pnsol[x], {x, 1, 6}]

xnsol = x /. 
    First@NDSolve[x[0] == 2 && eli2 /. p -> pnsol, x, {t, 0, .1}]

Plot[xnsol[t], {t, 0, .1}]

Plot[pnsol[xnsol[t]], {t, 0, .1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider p[x[t]] as a function of t. Then you can solve:

```
DSolve[{D[p[t], t] == x[t]^2, D[x[t], t] == p[t] x[t]^2}, {p, x}, t]
(*
{{x -> Function[{t}, 
    C[1] + 1/
      2 InverseFunction[
        ArcTan[#1/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[1]])]/(4 Sqrt[2] C[1]^(3/2)) + #1/(
          4 C[1] (2 C[1] + #1^2)) &][t/4 + C[2]]^2], 
  p -> Function[{t}, 
    InverseFunction[
      ArcTan[#1/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[C[1]])]/(4 Sqrt[2] C[1]^(3/2)) + #1/(
        4 C[1] (2 C[1] + #1^2)) &][t/4 + C[2]]]}}
*)
```

You see that p and x are function of some fun:= InverseFunction[...] and two arbitrary constants c[1] and c[2]. The constants are determined by additional conditions.

To further simplify we may set z= t/4+ C[2]:

```
{x -> c[1] + 1/2 fun[z^2], p -> fun[z]}
```

Comment: I should have been more clear: this is just a MWE , I am interested in a general method of solution